# Flannel failed to start when installing kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm installing kubernetes, but docker and kube-apiserver both failed to start. Through journal, finding that the reason is flannel. So I try to start flannel but it failed. Here is the output info:

```
Job for flanneld.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status flanneld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then I typed `systemctl status flanneld.service`, and here is the result:

```
● flanneld.service - Flanneld overlay address etcd agent

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/flanneld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: activating (start) since Fri 2018-01-26 03:28:08 EST; 51s ago
Main PID: 5870 (flanneld)
Memory: 6.5M

CGroup: /system.slice/flanneld.service

           └─5870 /usr/bin/flanneld -etcd-endpoints=http://127.0.0.1:2379 -etcd-prefix=/atomic.io/network


Jan 26 03:28:50 node-1 flanneld-start[5870]: E0126 03:28:50.755931    5870 network.go:102] failed to retrieve network config: 100: Key not found (/atomic.io) [23858]
```

Is there anyone can help me on this?

Comment: What is the *relevant* output from `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: Hello, finally I solved the problem by deleting the dependency of flannel. Thank you all the same!

Comment: How are you installing your cluster using kubeadm?

Comment: @sfgroups Hello, I haven't finished installing till now, many problems occured...

Comment: Is your cluster working now as expected?

Comment: @sfgroups emmmm now the master node works well, but problems arised when joining nodes...

Answer (score 0):

Curl the endpoint you have defined. You may need to point flannel to your master node.

```
/etc/sysconfig/flanneld
FLANNEL_ETCD_ENDPOINTS="http://<master ip>:2379"
FLANNEL_ETCD_PREFIX="/kube-centos/network"
```

Try that and then restart flanneld.